# Where did evaluating and produce go in ScalaTest 3?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, exception, testing, scalatest

Trying to use table-driven property checks to test invalid argument combinations based on the below example found [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/table_driven_property_checks) under **Testing invalid argument combinations** (bottom of the page, `should` replaced with `must`) using [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) 3.0.1, my class extending `WordSpec with TableDrivenPropertyChecks with MustMatchers`:

```
forAll (invalidCombos) { (n: Int, d: Int) =>
  evaluating {
    new Fraction(n, d)
  } must produce [IllegalArgumentException]
}
```

However, IntelliJ IDEA `cannot resolve symbol evaluating` and `cannot resolve symbol produce`. Now checking MustMachers documentation in [1.8](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/index.html#org.scalatest.matchers.MustMatchers) I found both `evaluating` and `produce`, but not in those of [3.0.0](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.MustMatchers) or [3.0.1](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalatest.MustMatchers). The [Migrating to 3.0](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/migrating_to_30) page says nothing about it. Where did they go and how can I use them in ScalaTest 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`evaluating` keyword has removed in **ScalaTest 3**, you need to use `an [Exception] should be thrownBy { ... }` to instead `evaluating`, like:

```
an [IllegalArgumentException] should be thrownBy {
  new Fraction(n, d)
}
```